# How does the double exclamation (!!) work in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I’m going through the Discover Meteor demo, and am struggling to figure out how exactly 'return !! userId;' works in [this section](https://github.com/DiscoverMeteor/Microscope/commit/chapter7-2):

```
Posts.allow({
  insert: function(userId, doc) {
    // Only allow posting if you are logged in
    return !! userId;
  }
});
```

Comment: Here's a dupe question, with a ton of answers as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784929/what-is-the-not-not-operator-in-javascript

Answer (score 562, accepted):

`!` is the logical negation or "not" operator. `!!` is `!` twice. It's a way of casting a "truthy" or "falsy" value to `true` or `false`, respectively. Given a boolean, `!` will negate the value, i.e. `!true` yields `false` and vice versa. Given something other than a boolean, the value will first be converted to a boolean and then negated. For example, `!undefined` will first convert `undefined` to `false` and then negate it, yielding `true`. Applying a second `!` operator (`!!undefined`) yields `false`, so in effect `!!undefined` converts `undefined` to `false`.

In JavaScript, the values `false`, `null`, `undefined`, `0`, `-0`, `NaN`, and `''` (empty string) are "falsy" values. All other values are "truthy."[<sup>(1):7.1.2</sup>](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf) Here's a truth table of `!` and `!!` applied to various values:

| value | !value | !!value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| false | true | false |
| true | false | true |
| null | true | false |
| undefined | true | false |
| 0 | true | false |
| -0 | true | false |
| 1 | false | true |
| -5 | false | true |
| NaN | true | false |
| '' | true | false |
| 'hello' | false | true |

Comment: Note worthy (as with "hello")
`!!"false"`
#=> `true`

Comment: It seems that it works the same as the [JavaScript Boolean method](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/javascript-boolean)

Comment: JavaScript Boolean method Example: `console.log(Boolean(12));` > `true`

Comment: Why may one need to convert, for example, a falsy value into a false boolean using `!!`?

Comment: @SergeyZolotarev I've seen this being used: `let array = [1, 2 ,3]; !!array.length && ...do something...`

Comment: Good answer but add two more that confuse people: " " (space) and "0" are True, and not false as one expects. This is why I dont care for "Truthy" statements or the ! operator. They arent robust enough to catch lots of edge cases.

Comment: @Stokely What you described are not "edge cases". In JS, an empty string is falsey and non-empty strings are truthy. Doesn't matter what is contained inside the string, a non-empty string is a non-empty string. 

What you may be confused about is when using the `==` operator to compare two operands. This will coerce values to some other type for the sake of the comparison and give unexpected results. You're better off using `===` or `!==` for comparison in JS as it will take into account the type and not do any conversion. https://stackoverflow.com/a/359509/2565869