# Vue v-if statement to check if variable is empty or null

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am trying to use a `v-if` statement to show some HTML only if the `archiveNote` variable is not empty/null.

```html
<div v-if="archiveNote === null || archiveNote ===''" class="form-check ml-3" id="include-note-div">
```

Here is how it's instantiated

```js
export default {
    name: "ConfirmReleaseFilesModal",
    props: {
        archiveName: String,
        archiveNote: String
    },
```

which is then passed in from this other Vue file

```html
<confirm-release-files-modal
    v-if="showConfirmReleaseFilesModal"
    @cancel="closeModal"
    @confirmAndEmail="releaseAction"
    @confirmNoEmail="releaseAction"
    :archive-name="archiveName"
    :archive-note ="archiveNote"
>
</confirm-release-files-modal>
```

The block of HTML still shows when `archiveNote` is `console.log` out as empty

Comment: where is the console? is it modified after the fact?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

If you want to show the `<div>` only when it is [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) (not empty/null/etc.), you can simply do:

```html
<div v-if="archiveNote">
```

This gives the same result as the [*double bang*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29312123/how-does-the-double-exclamation-work-in-javascript):

```html
<div v-if="!!archiveNote">
```

Both of these expressions evaluate all 8 of JavaScript's [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) values to `false`:

- `false`
- `null`
- `undefined`
- 0
- -0
- `NaN`
- `''`
- `0n` (BigInt)

and everything else to `true`. So if your variable evaluates to anything but these it will be truthy, and the `v-if` will show.

Here's a demo of these and some truthy examples:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      falsy: {
        'null': null,
        'undefined': undefined,
        '0': 0,
        '-0': -0,
        '\'\'': '',
        'NaN': NaN,
        'false': false,
        '0n': 0n
      },
      truthy: {
        '[]': [],
        '{}': {},
        '\'0\'': '0',
        '1': 1,
        '-1': -1,
        '\' \'': ' ',
        '\'false\'': 'false',
        '5': 5
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
#falsy, #truthy {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 49%;
}
.label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 80px;
  text-align: right;
}
code {
  background: #dddddd;
  margin: 0 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div id="falsy">
    Falsy:
    <div v-for="(test, label) in falsy">
      <div class="label">{{ label }}</div>
      <code v-if="test">true</code>
      <code v-else>false</code>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div id="truthy">
    Truthy examples:
    <div v-for="(test, label) in truthy">
      <div class="label">{{ label }}</div>
      <code v-if="test">true</code>
      <code v-else>false</code>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am writing this answer as the accepted answer did not work for me.

My object was empty but still was being evaluated as **truthy**.

> **Note:** My object was an `array` (json like) so I have used `Object.keys()>0` as a if conditional to check if the array is empty. I think its a better and a more reliable way to check if your array is empty. This solution would only work on arrays as per my knowledge

```json
{
    "__v_isShallow": false,
    "__v_isRef": true,
    "_rawValue": {},
    "_value": {}
}
```

So, a better solution is to check
`v-if="Object.keys(archiveNote).length > 0"` or

## Answer

here is a snippet demonstrating the same :

```js
const app = Vue.createApp({
    data() {
        return {
            archiveNote: ['Note 1', 'Note 2', 'Note 3'] // Example array
        };
    }
});

app.mount('#app');
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Vue.js Demo</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/3.4.8/vue.global.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <!-- Using v-if with Object.keys(archiveNote) > 0 -->
        <div v-if="Object.keys(archiveNote).length > 0">
            Display something because archiveNote is not empty.
        </div>

        <!-- Using v-if=archiveNote.length -->
        <div v-if="archiveNote.length">
            Display something because archiveNote is not empty.
        </div>
        
    </div>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>




<div v-if="!!archiveNote">
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be caused by the fact that in the parent component you are assigning your variables to incorrectly named props `:archive-name="archiveName"` instead of `:archiveName="archiveName"`.

Comment: this doesn't seem to be the case [doc](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Prop-Casing-camelCase-vs-kebab-case)