# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'includes') on clicking checkbox

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

[Link to CodeSandbox code with live project preview](https://codesandbox.io/s/toromont-used-equipment-fw66jm?file=/src/pages/listings/functions/getFilteredSearchResults.ts)

[Link to product page where checkbox is present](https://fw66jm.csb.app/en/products)

I've written a piece of code that, when a user goes to the product page and clicks on a checkbox called, "Show Consignment Products Only", it only shows products that have the word "CONSIGNMENT" in the product's name:

```
// Consignment Only
    if (filters.consignmentOnly &&
      !p.model.includes("CONSIGNMENT")) ||
      ...) {
        return false;
    }
```

When a user does so at this point, the below TypeScript error comes up:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'includes')
```

It looks like it's saying `model` is undefined (`model` refers to the model value in the API data), however I've used `model` and other values from this API many times and things load fine.

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`p.model` is not defined. Try:

```
if (filters.consignmentOnly && (!!p.model && !p.model.includes("CONSIGNMENT"))
```

The [double exclamation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29312123/how-does-the-double-exclamation-work-in-javascript) lets us check the boolean value of `p.model`.

`!!p.model` will return [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) or [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy). If truthy, `p.model.includes` is cleared to proceed. If falsy, it will end the condition there.

Answer (score 0):

You can try optional chaining:

```
// Consignment Only
if (filters.consignmentOnly && !p.model?.includes("CONSIGNMENT") || ...) {
    return false;
}
```